# How can I resolve the error String reference not set to an instance of a string?

Tags: c#, windows-services, setup-project, class-library

I create a C# Class Librairy for my project in order to communicate with my database.
I create a windows service for my project and for the windows service installation I create a setup project.

I wanted to encrypt my connection string so in the projectInstaller of my windows service I do this :

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    string directoryPath = Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"];
    string connectionStringSetting = Context.Parameters["DB_CONNECTION"];

    string cryptConnectionString = extract.EncryptStr(connectionStringSetting, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptKeyProject"]);

    string xml = directoryPath + "WindowsService1.exe.config";

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(xml);

    XmlNode connectionStringNode = document.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='DBContext ']");
    connectionStringNode.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = cryptConnectionString;

    document.Save(xml);
}
```

And in the class library (my database communication) of my project I decrypt the connection string

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{    
    public DBContext ()
    {
        ExtractLicenseData extract = new ExtractLicenseData();

        string encryptConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBContext"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        string decryptConnectionString = extract.DecryptStr(encryptConnectionString, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptKeyProject"]);

        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBContext"].ConnectionString = decryptConnectionString;    
    }   
}
```

The issue is when I try to install my project I have this error :

> Error 1001 : String reference not set to an instance of a String.
>
> Parameter name : s

Someone have any solution for me ?

Comment: What's `extract` in your code?

Comment: @MKR `extract` is a class which give the result of a encrypt/decrypt string thinks to an `encrypt_key`

Comment: Trailing space in 'DBContext ' and "DBContext "?

Comment: Perhaps not getting value for `connectionStringSetting ` in `string connectionStringSetting = Context.Parameters["DB_CONNECTION"];`

Comment: @EylM My fault when I copy/paste

Comment: @MKR even if I write the value of my connection string directly in `connectionStringSetting` I have the error.

Comment: Comment out EncryptStr function and check if you get error.

Comment: @MKR when I comment it I have no error the issue comes from this `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptKeyProject"]` I don't have access to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptKeyProject"]` ?

Comment: One of those methods returns a `null` value, which is then passed on to the next function call. **Step through the code**, checking string values on each line as you go, until you find the one that's null. If this only happens in a context where you can't step through the code (ie, your installer), add logging that does the checks for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptKeyProject"]`

If you want to have access to the setting you have to do this :

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
KeyValueConfigurationElement encryptKey = config.AppSettings.Settings["encryptKeyLicense"];
string cryptConnectionString = extract.EncryptStr(connectionStringSetting, encryptKey.Value.ToString());
```

And it will work !